# The drawbacks of the LBP image feature extraction method

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

The LBP feature has the drawback that it is not too robust on flat image areas.

Questions:

1. What is a flat image?
2. What do we mean by "not being robust on flat
   image areas"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image region is said to be "flat" if it has a nearly uniform intensity. In other words, the variance of the intensity values within the region is very low.

The LBP feature is not robust on "flat" image areas since it is based on intensity differences. Within flat image regions, the intensity differences are of small magnitude and highly affected by image noise. Moreover, they are ignorant of the actual intensity level at the location they are computed on.